# Unable to import com.vaadin.data.util.PropertysetItem

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

Just tried importing PropertysetItem after adding vaadin dependency which I have mentioned below but was unable to import. Can anyone help me for finding the right dependency

```
   dependency added
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I would like to point out that 8.4.0 is really old and outdated version. The latest Vaadin version is 8.12.4.

Comment: Noted. thankyou @TatuLund for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`PropertysetItem` as well as other related classes have been moved to the `com.vaadin.v7.data.util` package. You thus need to update your `import` statements to take the new package name into account.